# Vertically center text and image inside floating div

Tags: css

I've seen an article about vertical centering of text and image. I've seen an article about vertical centering text inside a floated div.

But not both conditions.

Here's my experiment:

```css
.phase {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.float-right {
  float: right;
}
.carousel {
  height: 300px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
.circle {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
.thumbnail {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="phase">
  <div class="float-right">
    <div class="carousel">
      <div class="circle">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo231.png" style="width:160px;height:160px;vertical-align:middle" />

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>I love css</h1>
</div>
```

Notice the image is vertically centered, but the green circle is not vertically centered.

**How can I get both the image and the green circle vertically centered?**

Comment: You want it vertically centered to the yellow box or the outer red box?

Comment: @TylerH, I will edit my question to make it clear I want both the circle and the image centered. The orange box (which you call yellow). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve a totally centered element using `calc` and view-units:

```css
#example {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: calc(50vh - 50px);
    left: calc(50vw - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```

This example will keep it right in the centre even with scrolling, etc - but you could place it centre based on the initial view using an absolute position.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the circle in a container and set the container's `line-height` property. Try this:

```css
.phase {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.float-right {
  float: right;
}
.carousel {
  height: 300px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
.container {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  line-height: 300px;
}
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
.thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="phase">
  <div class="float-right">
    <div class="carousel">
      <div class="container"><div class="circle">
      </div></div>
      <div class="container"><div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo231.png" style="width:160px;height:160px;vertical-align:middle" />
      </div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not working in my browser (Chrome). The image is not vertically centered. It's vertically at the top. Also, my code changed slightly since you copied it.

Comment: I tried it in Chrome and IE, and it works exactly the same in both. I see the circle next to the grey bar near the bottom of your Google image. Try it in full page and let me know.

Comment: That's where I see it too, next to the grey bar. The image is not vertically centered in the orange box; that's the problem. You got the circle centered but lost the image centering in the process. :)

Comment: Ahhhh, now I see what you're talking about. I was focusing on the circle. For the image, you only had to repeat what I did for the circle, i.e. wrap it with the same container. See my updated answer.

Comment: I voted it up b/c it's a solution, although it adds the extra structure. If the `calc` thing doesn't work out I have a plan B. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

My fixed code. It works in IE and in Chrome.

`top: calc(0.5vh + 50px);` is what does the trick. `50px` of course would be the height of the element you want to vertically center.

```css
.phase {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}

.carousel {
  height: 300px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: calc(0.5vh + 50px);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}

.thumbnail {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="phase">
  <div class="float-right">
    <div class="carousel">
      <div class="circle">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo231.png" style="width:160px;height:160px;" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>I love css</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this will work, but remember that `calc` and `vh` are not supported in older browsers.